# Question about a LSTM using python to predict stock prices

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I successfully copied the code from a tutorial and implemented a basic LSTM network to predict stock prices. The tutorial is here: https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/stock-price-prediction-in-python-using-tensorflow-2-and-keras

Upon adding additional feature columns I was not improving the model, so I tried something very basic to try to better understand what is going on.

Suppose the feature columns are ["date","price","volume"]
I then added an additional feature column, "nextDayPrice" with the data from the "next row".

Obviously, this data would not be available with a "stock price prediction model", but I wanted to test it out to see if the model accuracy approached 100% (as I would expect)

Given that one of the inputs is the exact price for the next day (not practical), shouldn't the accuracy of the model approach 100%?

The model does not seem to improve. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another input to your model. It is not enough just to add the feature to dataset.

If you labels are the same as input - the accuracy should be 100%.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I believe that I did add the feature to the inputs, but will test further. Another attempt to test this question, I added mock data, incrementing price by $1 per day. So day 1 = $1, day 300 = $300, etc... Interestingly the model sometimes approaches 100% accuracy, but does not get there. After 50 epochs, the model actually starts to get worse, and then heads back toward 100%, but still doesn't predict the next day's "price" 100% accurately. Is this a function of the LTSM designed to not overfit? Obviously most models are not trying to predict a basic linear function.

Comment: LSTM is not designed to prevent overfitting. Why do you think that most models are not trying to predict linear function ? If you don't add non-linear activation - all the models are linear

Comment: The way that I built it, there is a dropout layer, with a 0.4 dropout rate. It seems like that would explain the model's inability to converge on 100% accuracy in my example where the train_y (target) is included as an input. Does that sound right?

Comment: Yes, dropout prevents overfitting to some extent

Comment: Thanks! For others reading this, I read about regularization and the use of dropout with input and hidden layers here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/dropout-for-regularizing-deep-neural-networks/